# MyUItableview is massed up when scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll

I have developed a chat application supporting text and images and presented in a UITableView.
  When there are few pages of data and I scroll, the view is messed up, some images are cut since it seems the cell got less height, the space between each cell is reducing etc..

I thought about pagination but this will not have since even with 20 cells i get that problem

Answer (score 0):

Try get them to autosize ... https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells

so that way they'll adjust depending on what is in the cell (image/text ...)

Comment: This I have done they are looking well but once I scroll they starting to mess up

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what they look like when they're messed up? ... Also are you using autolayout? Your constraints may be causing this possibly.